# How to click a button created using <span> tag for Selenium webdriver using python?

Tags: html, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, selenium-chromedriver

I have to click the following tag button which is a part of an infinite scrolling page.

```
<span> Show More Results </span>
```

I have tried the following but it didn't help

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath('.//span[Show More Results]').click()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with

`.//span[contains(text(),'Show More Results')]`

In your case it seems like you missed quotes around 'Show More Results' and also consider any white spaces

Comment: Thanks, but I had found another way to handle this.